# Add current page url into html

Tags: javascript, get

I am trying to fetch and insert the current page url into some html for some custom social sharing on a wordpress site.

I am using Visual Composer and so have inserted a custom JS block and inserted the script

I have tried 
`document.getElementById("myLink").href = document.URL;`

but then I need to insert it within a url as I need sharing links. I have been generating these from www.sharelinkgenerator.com

So for example, facebook would be

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=link-i-want-to-share">Share on Facebook</a>
```

So I would need to fetch and place the url in place of 'link-i-want-to-share' and similar for twitter, linkedin and email

The html I currently have is:

```
<div class="slideouticons horizontal">
```

```
<div class="iconswrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="share-url-here" class="socicon-twitter" title="Twitter" target="_blank"></a></li>
<li><a href="share-url-here" class="socicon-facebook" title="Facebook"></a></li>
<li><a href="share-url-here" class="socicon-linkedin" title="Google Plus"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: "but I get a console syntax error" — I can't see a syntax error there. What **exactly** does the error message say?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the initial post

Comment: You have double quotes wrapping double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> alert("document.getElementById("myLink").href = document.URL;" )
> ```

This does have syntax errors in it (you can't have unescaped double quotes inside a string literal delimited with double quotes), but it doesn't make any sense to have that as a string in the first place.

If you want the code to run, then you can't put it in a string.

Just have the code you want to run.

```
document.getElementById("myLink").href = document.URL;
```

Comment: Okay - the Visual composer block had an 'insert code here' section which is what i did, perhaps I shouldn't have used this insertion method at all.

If I fix that, how would I write the html to insert the url?

Thanks